# Use jdbc to connect to remote mysql via ip, but the ip becomes another ip

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I want to connect to a remote mysql database and fill in an IP address, but what is prompted here is another IP address（My local ip). What should I do? How can I solve it?
I haven't searched related questions, only found a `jdbc: rmi://`, but mysql does not seem to need rmi.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection to the remote server succeeded. But the user connecting is not allowed to. The message you've got is from MySQL. 
So you need to use a user that can connect remotely or you need to grant access for 'root'@'171.221.xxx.yyy' e.g. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on database.* to 'root'@'171.221.xxx.yyy' identified by 'aPassword'